# Routing in ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a following scenario:

Producer P produces messages posts all of them to AMQ 'A' (which is local to 'P').

Is it possible for me to route the messages from ActiveMQ A to remote Active MQs B or C?

Basically Iam looking for filters in 'A' side configuration to route these messages.

Thanks in Advance, 
Madhav

Gaurav,

What I mean is I have 3 instances of activeMQs at location A, B and C respectively, I have a producer bean 'P' in location A which locally places the messages in AMQ instance @A, locally because I relieve the headache of connection maintenance(lessen) and probability of message loss in 'P' if I were to connect to AMQ instances B or C remotely.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to interconnect the 3 brokers, then just create a [network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) out of them...then producers and consumers can connect to any broker and messages can flow to the appropriate broker based on demand, etc.

otherwise, if you want more explicit control, then you can use [Camel](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) to perform basic (or complex) routing from brokerA queues to broker B/C queues using separate connection factories, etc.